# How to disable Special Characters in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter

I have a Firstname and Lastname fields, I have set rules to 'required' but I want to both fields must only accept Letters not special characters or numeric. If user submit with special character or numeric i want to display an error message that user submit invalid characters.

Comment: Keep in mind that some languages use extra characters that aren't present in the plain english alphabet... consequently there are also names with "special" characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to the validation the `alpha` rule.

Read more [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html) under `Rule Reference`.